# Migrating from SVN to Git in a production environment

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migrate

I have been tasked with migrating from SVN to Git, but I am unsure how to do so with the current setup in place. Here is how the SVN repository works at the moment:

We have a development server and a production server, both of which are connected to a single SVN repository. We make changes locally and save it to the development server. Whenever we are satisfied with these changes, we commit them to the svn repository from the development server (svn commit...), then update them on the production server (svn update...)

We now want to use Git, but I am unsure how to reflect the same or similar behaviour. I initially thought of having a single Git repository with two branches (dev and master). The only thing is, both the development and production servers are not in sync; there are a lot of files with changes on them on the development server and vice versa. How best can I approach this dilemma?

Edit: I see this far too often. Please specify a reason for downvoting so I can improve my answer.

Comment: It would be easier if you had already separated your version control from your deployment process (i.e. not just using a live working copy on the production server).

Comment: @crashmstr That would be ideal. I'm working with an old setup though, from previous developers.

Comment: Even if there is just a batch file or shell script to copy stuff to the servers, you want to get your deployment into a different process at this point. That allows you to work with different deployments, feature branches, etc.

Comment: That's the plan!

Answer (score 2):

Git and SVN are both version control systems, but they don't work in exactly the same way. They have different workflows.

Git is a distributed version control system, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control

I would suggest starting with a single shared Git repository with a single branch, and a local repository on each developer's workstation. Create the developers' repositories by cloning the shared repo. Then you have to get used to adding an additional step into your workflow: on SVN you used to just 'commit', on Git you will have to 'commit' and then also 'push' to the shared repository.

Then read the Git from SVN page here: https://git-scm.com/course/svn.html
This will help you understand Git from an SVN perspective.

Comment: Having a local repo on each dev's workspace is something we were discussing. We want to have the ability to have different environments for different purposes though. For example, a development environment and a production environment. We also want the ability to add more environments, such as a staging environment. In this case, is it as simple as committing and pushing to a dev branch, then rebase that into the staging branch and / or the master (live) branch?

Comment: You will have to have a local repo on each dev's workspace, that is the only way that distributed version control works. For different environments you would then use different branches, correct. In that case, you would commit and then push to the dev branch and then *merge* from develop to the other branch.